# How do I configure cors-anywhere rate limit and whitelist?

Tags: javascript, heroku, proxy, cors-anywhere

I'm relatively new to web development and I just want to know how I can configure my own version of cors-anywhere before I host it on heroku.

I currently have the cors-anywhere folder with all of its node-modules downloaded and I want to know how to configure the rate limit so that there is no limit for my website only.

Edit: I also don't know whether or not I should create my own javascript file to configure it or if I should change the files in cors-anywhere directly before hosting it to heroku.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, for heroku you have to use the terminal command `heroku config:set ENVIRONMENTVARIABLE=value` for environment variables on heroku apps. From here, you can simply set your environment variables in correspondance with cors-anywhere syntax

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.